# which is good method sending 50mb data at one slot or any other way to send 50mb json data to the server in android?

Tags: android

**which is good way to send big amount of data to server ?**

at on time request or in one slot?
 sending data in small parts?
 any another option please?

Comment: [Compressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) would be a first step. As Androids do not have a guaranteed internet connection and might suffer from quota adn speed throttling, it is a practical, user context depending decision - you have to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get smaller using something like Protocol Buffers:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Your best bet if you still have a lot of data is to chunk the data and send it in pieces.  Look at the common design patterns of Frame Decoder and Encoder, with examples of how these are used in practice here:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html